# Complex nested IF/OR Statement

Tags: excel

First post so let me say Excel is NOT my strong suit. I am trying to achieve results using IF/OR, but that may be the wrong choice. All advice and direction will be appreciated.

I have a spreadsheet. Cell F2 will always have the text "TANK" or "CYLINDER". Cell C2 will always have a number. I need to return "PASS" or "FAIL" flag in cell G2 based on the value in C2, BUT those values differ based on the text in F2.

Explanation:

> IF F2=TANK & C2<=19 - return PASS,
>   IF F2=TANK & C2>=20 - return FAIL,
>   or
>   IF F2=CYLINDER & C2<=20 - return PASS,
>   IF F2=CYLINDER & C2>=21 - return FAIL,

Below is one of many options I have tried and apparently I don't know what I'm doing. Any help is appreciated...Thanks

```
=IF(OR(F2="TANK",F2="CYLINDER"),IF(F2="TANK",IF(C2<=19,"PASS",IF(C2>=20,"FAIL")))),IF(F2="CYLINDER",IF(C2<=20,"PASS",IF(C2>=21,"FAIL")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it much, but this should be what you are looking for:

```
=IF(AND(F2="TANK",C2<=19),"PASS",IF(AND(F2="CYLINDER",C2>=20),"FAIL",IF(AND(F2="CYLINDER",C2<=20),"PASS",IF(AND(F2="CYLINDER",C2>=21),"FAIL"))))
```

Comment: I had to change "CYLINDER" to "TANK" just before C2>=20, but other than that it worked beautifully...Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working version:

```
=IF(F2="TANK",IF(C2<=19,"PASS","FAIL"),IF(F2="CYLINDER",IF(C2<=20,"PASS","FAIL"),"not tank or cylinder"))
```

However, as you've noticed, long strings of functions within functions all on one line become extremely difficult to read and debug!

You can split up the intermediate steps in your formula into seperate cells - this makes it much easier to see what's going on at a glance.  For example, you could have a cell that calculates the maximum value for pass/fail:

```
A1:  if(F2="TANK", 20, if (F2="CYLINDER", 21, -1))
A2:  if(C2>=A1,"PASS","FAIL")
```

(the "-1" is a final "else" case, if neither "TANK" nor "CYLINDER" is true)

Other ideas:  if you've got three or more cases (tank, cylinder, widget, thimble...), you can use a vlookup function to return the maximum value.  See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1